# Delete nodes if URL is called via Wget Command

Tags: nodes, cron

How can I delete the `nodes` if i am calling my `URL` via `wget` command. Because the `anonymous` user haven't permission to `edit/delete`.

Comment: why anonymous user edit/delete nodes?

Comment: No i want to set a cron call of url. So that will be as anonymous user. I want to delete the nodes in my function. So problem is that i can't give permission to anonymous user of edit/delete nodes. And it will not delete the nodes if call from anonymous user.

Comment: You can set node edit/delete permissions for anonymous user at admin/people/permissions/list, can't you?

Comment: Yes i but i don't want to give permission.

Comment: Have you tried node_delete()?

Comment: I tried only `node_delete()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using following code :

```
global $user;
$owner_account = user_load(array('uid' => UID));
$temp_user = $user;
$user = $owner_account;
node_delete(NID);
$user = $temp_user;
```

Comment: how $user and $owner_account are related with node_delete()?

Comment: This will load the user account of account creator or any id that i will provide who have permission to delete the content. So no need to give the permission to anonymous user.

Comment: What are UID and NID in your answer?

Comment: `UID` is user id who have the permission and `NID` is node id which has to be deleted.

Comment: UID is the owner of the node to be deleted, right?

Comment: I believe [node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete/7) does not check delete permission as I said in my answer. See [node_delete_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7) which is a single call from node_delete().

Comment: No, it checks. I tried `node_delete` but it was not deliting the node. After that i used this step.

Comment: If you do this, you'll open a serious security hole, since anyone visiting that URI will able to delete nodes.

Comment: node_delete does not check access!

Comment: You loaded a user into the `$user`. Then call `node_delete()`. You can see that `$user` is not concerned with `node_delete()` if you check [node_delete_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7).

Comment: @BálintKléri yeah thats the problem form me, so that i asked it.

Answer (score 3):

[**Services module**](http://drupal.org/project/services) is great for this job. Here are the steps how you can make it work:

- Download [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services), [Chaos tools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) and [Libraries](http://drupal.org/project/libraries). Enable the **REST Server** module (shipped with Services), it will make you enable all dependencies as well.
- Go to *Structure » Services*, add a new endpoint.
- Choose a machine-readable name, e.g.: `node_remove`.
- Select *REST* as a server.
- Define a path to your endpoint, e.g.: `node-remove`.
- Enable debug mode, it's handy while you are experimenting, Services will write useful information to the log.
- Enable session authentication, this will ensure security.
- After saving your endpoint, edit its resources.
- Enable the *delete* operation in the *node* group and the *login* operation in the *user* group.
- Go to the *Server* tab, select the response formatters and request parsing options that you want.

Your endpoint is ready to use. First you need to post a username and password to `http://example.com/node-remove/user/login`. (It's recommended to create a user with a strong password and permissions for only deleting nodes.) You will get a session ID (among others) in the response. Then you need to perform a *DELETE* request to `http://example.com/node-remove/node/{nid}`. You can write a script for these actions and execute that as a cronjob.

Comment: I have a long script to run, So i dont want to use service module. I will check the IP address along with username and after that i will do my code. I know this is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with the following content and simply drop in the Drupal root directory.
Let's say anonymous-node-delete.php. You could add this URL with your cron command, for example, http://example.com/anonymous-node-delete.php?nids=1,2,3

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

if( isset($_GET['nids'])) {
    $nids = explode(',', $_GET['nids']);
    node_delete($nids);
}
```

I hope this will work. As everyone is accessible to this URL if s/he knows it, **use this as your own risk as this is lack of security.**

Comment: what is the difference in it?

Comment: what do you mean? Is this not are you looking for? Or I did not catch your point?

Comment: `node_delete()` will needs the delete node permission. As I said i dont want to give this permission to anonymous user.

Comment: i did it. check my answer. and thnx btw.